# Run Every 10th file in directory in parallel

Tags: bash, awk, command-line, grep, command-line-arguments

I have the command below in bash, which takes in input images in a directory, and executes the executable “execute”, and outputs some image results in “results” and some text annotations in the text file $file. The problem is I need to run it for every 10th file in parallel. It seems possible to write a shell script to process every 10th. However, I have not been able to get the parallel part to work. How can I pass a filename (of input image) as input parameter to –r, and still run in parallel? I've tried many things.

```
 for file in *.jpg; do ../../execute --model ../../modelsXX.txt -r $file.txt     
   --video ../results  --threshold=0 $file; done
```

links i tried:

[Grabbing every 4th file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71776/grabbing-every-4th-file)

[How to process every second file in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553751/how-to-process-every-second-file-in-bash)

Comment: Just what the heck is `execute`? What the heck does the `-r` option do? And where the heck are you executing in parallel? And what does it have to do with every 10th file?

Comment: @4ae1e1 it's an executable module. I want to execute for file in *.jpg for every 10th file, in parallel. Does that make sense? So it loops over a series of images. I need that to be in parallel and every 10th file. I can't get this to work.

Comment: Still can't quite fit everything you've said so far, but do you mean this? `counter=0; for file in *.jpg; do (( (counter++) % 10 )) && continue; execute blah blah "$file" & done; wait`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 
So, thanks a lot for the response, but what I really am stuck on is the parallel part. I need to run it in parallel with one command. So instead of using for loop, I tried something like the below, but I'm not able to pass in a filename parameter for $file.txt and store text output for every 10th image. Does that make sense? I thought for loop method would work, but I can't get solutions like yours above to work in parallel, so I tried below using seq: seq -f '%g.jpg' 1 10 1000 | parallel -j 4 ./../execute --model ../../modelsXX.txt -r --images results/ --threshold=0

Comment: My suggestion uses backgrounding, which is indeed parallel.

Comment: If you want to use GNU Parallel, read the documentation and tutorial. Pretty obvious stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This counts the number of files and whenever the file number modulo 10 is 7 (just to be more interesting than choosing 1, but you can use any value 0..9) runs your command in background, which allows the commands to run in parallel.

```
n=0
for file in *.jpg
do
    if [ $((++n % 10)) = 7 ]
    then ../../execute --model ../../modelsXX.txt -r $file.txt --video ../results --threshold=0 $file &
    fi
done
wait   # Wait for the jobs running in parallel to finish
```

---

> What I really am stuck on is the parallel part. I need to run it in parallel with one command.

In that case, simply echo every tenth name inside the loop, and pipe the output of the loop to the `parallel` command:

```
n=0
for file in *.jpg
do
    if [ $((++n % 10)) = 7 ]
    then echo $file
    fi
done |
parallel -j 4 ./../execute --model ../../modelsXX.txt -r --images results/ --threshold=0
```

Syntax of the `parallel` command untested and copied from your notes.

Comment: So, thanks a lot for the response, but what I really am stuck on is the parallel part. I need to run it in parallel with one command. So instead of using for loop, I tried something like the below, but I'm not able to pass in a filename parameter for $file.txt and store text output for every 10th image. Does that make sense? I thought for loop method would work, but I can't get solutions like yours above to work in parallel, so I tried below using seq:

         seq -f '%g.jpg' 1 10 1000 |  parallel -j 4 ./../execute --model     ../../modelsXX.txt -r  --images results/ --threshold=0

Comment: The problem is  that when I run this, I need to pass in $file as an input to -r (see first post above). When I run your above solution, I get following error on bas  "More than one image/dataset provided". Does that make sense?

Comment: So your solution works, except I can't get $file output as text file. Make sense?

Comment: So, you want parallel to run 4 copies of your program, with one file name inserted after the `-r` option and before the `--images` option?  Have you looked at the documentation for GNU [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html)?  Doesn't it explain how to do that?  And given that you want to run the commands one at a time in parallel, what's up with using `&` as I originally showed which does the same job?  What's the advantage of using the `parallel` program?

Comment: Nominally, you can use `{}` where you want your file name:  `parallel -j 4 ./../execute --model ../../modelsXX.txt -r {}.txt --images results/ --threshold=0 {}`.  You might need some extra syntax; I'm not a user of `parallel`.